# inputs not filling entire width of bootstrap column in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am having the hardest time of getting my inputs to fill the max width of a bootstrap column in a MVC 5 project. I added a view and added the layout page to the view (nothing fancy, just the normal layout page that comes with a typical MVC project). If you run the snippet I provided, my inputs are filling the given width of the bootstrap column, but when I run this code in my app, its not filling the width of the column.

Is there anything in particular that would cause my screenshot to look like it does and not how it is in my snippet?

here is the screenshot ( the multicolored columns are for a point of reference for me )

[image: In my MVC view]

```css
.max-size {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:blue">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:red">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:purple">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:yellow">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:green">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:orange">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:blue">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:red">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:purple">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:yellow">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:green">col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background:orange">col-md-1</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        ABC
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row max-size">
          <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control max-size" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Department" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Department" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Department" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Department" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Department" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Department" />
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
                  <center>Cancel</center>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                  <center>Submit</center>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        CBA
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they can't go full  width  cause their parent have a col-md-6 put 12 and it will work 
i mean here

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row max-size">
          <div class="col-md-12">
```

also try  to  read more about nesting   here is a link http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Comment: If thats the case then why do my buttons, which is in the col-md-6, stretch properly?

Comment: cause they  are in a new row of col-md-12 while they  input are in col-md-6